# Weather and clothing for Jungfraujoch, Switzerland

Tags: switzerland, weather-and-climate

I am an Indian citizen from Chennai, India. I am 68 years young and am travelling to Switzerland with my wife, 67 years young. Our travel is scheduled between the 17th and 20th of August, 2019.

Please let me know what would be the average temperature during this period, and generally speaking, what types of clothes we should take with us, particularly for an excursion to Jungfraujoch and Mt. Titlis.

Would we be able to rent boots and warm jackets for the day at Jungfraujoch to safeguard us from ice and snow?

Would we need to carry any medicine to prevent from high altitude sickness?

Answer (score 9):

It still will be summer in Switzerland in August, so temperatures in most places (especially cities) are between 15 and 30 °C (60 - 90 °F). In the mountains it's fresher (not that this is a surprise), expect something between 0 and 15 °C (32 - 60 °F; that's air temperature, it will feel colder or warmer depending on wind and/or sunshine).

Details of course depend on your itinerary so you may want to check out

- [Switzerland forecast](https://www.meteoswiss.admin.ch/home.html?tab=overview)
- [Weather on Jungfraujoch](https://www.jungfrau.ch/en-gb/live/weather/)
- [Weather on Titlis](https://www.titlis.ch/en/live/weather)

a few days before you leave, or during your trip.

As for clothing: If you just take the usual tourist trip to Jungfraujoch or Titlis, any closed boots should do (I wouldn't recommend sandals). Add a wind jacket, long trousers and maybe a second shirt or a sweater and you should be fine. On both destinations there are buildings on top so you also can enjoy the view without going outside if the weather conditions are really bad. In any case, don't forget sun protection and sun glasses!

PS: I won't give medical advice here, probably best to ask your doctor before departure. There are also some [medical tips published by Jungfrau Railways](https://www.jungfrau.ch/en-gb/faq/#7048), indicating that altitude sickness shouldn't be an issue but other conditions might.

Answer (score 2):

Hello and welcome to Switzerland.

I doubt it is possible to rent warm clothes - here people are expected to bring their own. They are available for purchase pretty much everywhere on open days (that means, not sundays) so aquiering them should not be an issue - and they are typically cheaper than a train ticket to Jungraujoch too so if you could afford the former you can certainly afford warm clothes.

Maybe don't wait to be in a very touristic place such as Interlaken, because there's a risk that prices are overmade - if you can prepare something in advance that's better.

Note that even if you were *not* going at high altitude you'd still need warm and/or waterproof clothes just in case, because even in summer depending on the weather it can be pretty cold especially in the morning, and also it's raining regularly.