# What to wear for a short excursion to Jungfraujoch and Mount Titlis in first week of May?

Tags: switzerland, clothing

I am 67 years old and my spouse 62 years young. We both are planning to go for a short excursion to Jungfraujoch in the first week of May by Cable Car followed by Cogwheel train and visit the Ice Palace and Sphinx Observatory Deck followed by lunch at Interlaken.

Next day we plan to visit Mount Titlis by the rotating cable car -Rotair and visit the cliff walk suspension bridge followed by a tour of Lucerne.

We don't intend to do any skiing at either place.

Kindly suggest what type of clothing and shoes we should pack for the above trips.

Comment: What are you used to? Tropical temperatures or artic conditions?

Comment: I'm not really sure about May; if nobody answers I'll do some research and post an answer, but for now I will just recommend layers, primarily because (especially at that time of year) you will want to be flexible. The variability from day to day is significant, and the high elevations will be rather cooler than the low, especially if it is sunny. With layers (and a day pack big enough to carry them if it's too warm to wear them all), you can be comfortable without knowing the day's weather precisely.  Which of course you probably won't when you pack your suitcase, otherwise why ask? :-)

Comment: @phoog, if your comment is this long it should be posted as an answer. And what is needed depends on what they are used to, which they have not provided yet

Comment: Related https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/142358/weather-and-clothing-for-jungfraujoch-switzerland?rq=1

Answer (score 5):

I'm less *pessimistic* compared the answer of @Willeke:

If there is sun, sun (radiation) is strong, so you may not need too many layers.

If it would be bad weather, sorry but you will not enjoy much and so you will not remain outdoor for long time (but it is *magic* walking in the clouds, where you may not full see your feet).

And on both case, you are not staying outdoor hours, and you will be near the building and so the restaurant to get warmer between short outdoor visits.

Just: get good shoes (and possibly a pair to change, if they become wet). And if you have more layers, the better: you can decide to wear one more. Unfortunately it takes baggage place (and maybe low use), so it is your decision.

If you go to Jungfrauhoch, I would not go to Titlis: both are touristy, but Titlis on a bad way. If you are near Jungfrauhoch, go to "Piz Gloria" (and so also a good view of a "Hobbit like valley", and in Lucerne: Pilatus: it is not so high, but Switzerland is not just glaciers).

Answer (score 2):

Your trip will get you so high up the mountain that the temperature will likely be below freezing and can be well below that, think the temperature inside a freezer.

What you need in clothing depends on what you are used to, someone who lives in an area where snow is around till late April will need much less than someone who lives in the tropics.

If you are from an area where snow never happens bring the warmest clothes you own, add them in layers and make sure you have a waterproof layer on the outside. A thin rain jacket will make a moderately warm layer under it a lot warmer. You can layer up to six layers of silk payama pants under your nice trousers without them showing and that is the kind of layering that might keep you warm enough.

If you have waterproof shoes which allow for two layers of socks bring those, otherwise shoes which are waterproof and fit well enough to walk long distances on.

Gloves or mittens and shawls or scarves and a warm hat for when you are in the coldest part of your tour.

For those who are from a less hot area, layers, waterproof outers, and hat, scarve and gloves as well as sensible shoes.

And of course, lower on the mountain the temperature will be higher and fewer layers needed.

Comment: OP can probably rent warm clothes in Interlaken.  No self-respecting Swiss business will fail to use an opportunity to make money out of affluent tourists ;-)